# Shared Database With Domain Access and Multiple Accounts With Same Email

Tags: users, domain-access

We are planning to have the following Drupal architecture:

- One install of Drupal.
- Multiple domains sharing the same database using the Domain Access module.

Each domain will have user login capabilities, and user accounts will not be shared across domains. This means we will have times when one email address could be associated with multiple accounts (one for each domain where the email address is associated with an account).

Is such an architecture possible using a shared database, or will we have problems trying to associate many accounts to the same email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Domain Access unless you are planning on sharing users and content between the different domains.  In your instance, you do not want to share users -- and yes, you would have problems if you tried to have duplicate user entries sharing the same email address.  You are therefore better off creating multiple independent Drupal sites, and replicating shared content (if any) via other means.